# How exactly does a symbolic link work?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I was told they were like "shortcuts" in windows, but I am not exactly sure if I did it right.

I have a MySQL database on my hard drive 1, under /var/lib/mysql/temp

but I want it to be located on drive 2, which can be accessed by `cd /drive2`, and I want every update and everything to occur on hard drive 2.

So what I did was:

```
ln -s /drive2/temp /var/lib/mysql/temp
```

and it seems to work, but everywhere I read it seems as if the syntax I used should have been the other way around.

Did I do it right?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are gonna vote down you might at least say why so that i can improve the question right?

Comment: Not my DV, but this is a question that can be answered really easily with a short trip to Google or Wikipedia, and since [SF] is a site for pro admins and not for beginners asking to learn about absolutely fundamental concepts, this question is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) anyway.

Comment: See the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Comment: And if you mouse over the down arrow, you'll see the text "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  Given what others have written above, I think you can reasonably assume that a downvote without comment is for exactly those reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you built the link `/var/lib/mysql/temp` pointing to `/drive2/temp`.
If your aiming to transfer dbs to /drive2, you should rather:

- stop mysql
- move files to drive2
- link newfolder to oldfolder | change db position in my.cnf
- restart mysql

Answer (score 0):

Symlink is s special file that contains a reference to another file or directory.

`ln`'s TARGET argument goes first and then comes the LINK_NAME. In your case it should be the reverse.